# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size') - Next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, parameters, urlsearchparams

Today, i come up with one problem that i'm using Next js 13.4 version with backend. so when i used searchParams in server side, it was throwing error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size') iam destructuring size and style search params. this is my code:

Iam performing add to cart functionlaity, which speaks to backend.
this is my addToCart function:

```
 const addToCartHandler = async () => {
    const style = Number(searchParams.get("style"));
    const size = searchParams.get("size");
    console.log("iam from front", style, Number(size));
    await axios
      .get(`/api/product/${product._id}?style=${style}&size=${size}`)
      .then((res) => console.log("data------>", res.data));       
  };
```

this is my product/[id]/route.ts:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connect from "../../../../utils/db";
export const GET = async (
  req: Request,
  { params, searchParams }: { params: any; searchParams: any }
) => {
  try {
    await connect();
    const { id } = params;
    const size = searchParams.size;
    const style = searchParams.style;
    console.log(id, size, style);
    return new NextResponse(id, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: any) {
    return new NextResponse(`${error}`, {
      status: 500,
      statusText: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

I have tried this above code after clicking add to cart button, it throws me
[image]

I think there's an error in backend.
**Please ignore it if you think this is stupid, it's a beginner mistake. :)**

Comment: do you understand that the error means `searchParams` is undefined?

Comment: Hey, I can see you can easily get size and style in Frontend but you are unable to access these in backend.

```const size = searchParams.size;
    const style = searchParams.style;
```
I know the backend is unable to access size but is it able to access style??

Comment: @NirajKumarChaurasiya yes sir, exactly!!!

Comment: Hey, did you rewrite your code as 
```const size = searchParams.get('size');
    const style = searchParams.get('style');```
in your backend in NextJS. Try it, maybe this will help you.

Comment: @NirajKumarChaurasiya if `searchParams.size` complains that `searchParams` is undefined, how likely do you think `searchParams.style` would work, on a scale out of 10?

Comment: @JaromandaX You are more senior than all of us, I didn't expect this from you. 
In coding, everything can happen. Sometimes, when we expect two arguments, we can get one easily but can't get the other.

I know you are a senior engineer but you also went from 0 to where you are, so you must know these types of errors can happen. I have also encountered many times this error, so to clarify I asked.

However, why are we discussing this, we should focus on fixing his problem.

Comment: @NirajKumarChaurasiya *these types of errors can happen* - that's why I asked the likelihood of it happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NodeJS's world, searchParams is an object that has many methods and doesn't directly returns a value. In this case, `searchParams.size` would equan an instance of `URLSearchParams` object, meaning `searchParams` equal to an `URLSearchParams` object, and `URLSearchParams.size` is `undefined`.

The right way to fix it would be

```
    const size = searchParams.get('size');
    const style = searchParams.get('style');
```

See official NodeJS doc for `searchParams` here https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlsearchparams